# discord.py circular import (AttributeError: partially initialized module 'discord')

Tags: python, discord.py, circular-dependency

I am trying to write a Discord bot, but the bot won't start and raises this error:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'discord' has no attribute 'Client' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header (before you have any functions or method calls) should include the following items:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

You also need to initialize your discord client. In this case, a client represents your script's connection to the discord server. If you don't initialize, none of your commands will work.

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
```

within the parenthesis, you can declare the prefix for your commands. Ex, .help vs !help.

Lastly, you need to connect your client to the server and run it in a continuous event loop. This should be at the end of your file.

```
client.run('your bot's token')
```

Answer (score 4):

If the name of your file is `discord.py` try to change the name `bot.py` for example

Comment: Would care to explain why changing the file name works? Is this documented somewhere or based on your experience?

Comment: @Arcanefoam answering for the poster, the two parts "partially initialized module" and "most likely due to a circular import" are major hints in Python that a circular import has occurred. And changing the file name is the correct solution.

Answer (score -3):

Try to define your bot / client

```
var client = new Discord.Client();
```

Comment: This isn't even the right language.