# Discord.py Errors

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

Today I wanted to try to create a discord bot with python. The problem i have is, that there is always an error message when I start the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\...\Discord Bot\PythonGPU_Bot\bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python39\lib\discord\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    client = discord.Client()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'discord' has no attribute 'Client' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Thats the Error message I always get.
This is my script:

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {}'.format(client.user.name))
    client.loop.create_task(status_task())


async def status_task():
    while True:
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('Hello <:'))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('Hello c:'))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.auther.bot:
        return
    if '.status' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send('SSSS')


client.run('ID')
```

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Is this helping you? [Discord Bot Coding (AttributeError: partially initialized module..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430624/discord-bot-coding-attributeerror-partially-initialized-module) - Also: Have you updated your `discord.py` version?

Comment: I already seen that post and it didnt help me out.  I also updated the discord.py maybe i have to reinstall it, but I dont know how.

Comment: Have you also tried to remove your client and replace it with: `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")` and import `from discord.ext import commands`? *Note that this will support `commands` for your bot*

Comment: Yes i tried it and the same issue appeard

Comment: Have you tried to re-name your file/program?

Comment: It is actually due to circular import. Rename your file!

Answer (score 0):

## The name of your file is `discord.py`, rename the file

rename it to `bot.py` or `main.py` or anything you like and your issue will be fixed

### Why does it happen?

Since your file name is `discord.py`, it is actually importing that file and not the actual `discord.py` module you installed with pip.